# ¿Diferencia entre BinaryOperator y BiFunction? Java 8

Tags: java-8

Estoy aprendido Java 8 , y todavía no me queda claro la diferencia entre **BinaryOperator** , y **BiFunction** .¿Alguien me puede explicar la diferencia?
Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como se puede leer en la documentación, [BinaryOperator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BinaryOperator.html) es una especialización de [BiFunction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html) porque éste último acepta operandos de tipos distintos y produce un resultado que puede ser también de cualquier tipo, pero el primero necesita operandos de tipos iguales y produce el resultado de ese mismo tipo.

Es decir `BinaryOperator` sólo trabaja con un tipo y `BiFunction` puede llegar a trabajar con tres tipos distintos.